# error in saving tiff files to a pdf file using ghostscript win64c

Tags: pdf, system, tiff, ghostscript, saving-data

i am running ghostscript win64c under matlab on a tiff file in order to convert it to pdf. i need to save *several* such tiff files in *one* pdf file.

i use this command:

command =
sprintf('gswin64c -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=%s -dBATCH %s', pdf_file, tifffilename);
system(command);

i get the following error message:

GPL Ghostscript 10.02.1 (2023-11-01)
Copyright (C) 2023 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Error: /undefined in II*
Operand stack:
Execution stack:   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1944   1   3   %oparray_pop   1943   1   3   %oparray_pop   1928   1   3   %oparray_pop   1801   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:   --dict:746/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:85/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 4
GPL Ghostscript 10.02.1: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

can you please help?

thanks a lot!!!

MAT

Comment: Actually Ghostscript can, with the use of a suitable program, interpret a TIFF file. I've posted one on Stack Overflow in the past. There's a link in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211428/conversion-of-tiff-to-pdf-with-ghostscript Also GhostPDL (which is part of the family) can read TIFF and some other formats directly.  But you are correct that without additional support (eg a PostScript program) Ghostscript can't read image formats.